# Saving image from the Imagebutton to the sqllite and then retrieving it in an imageview

Tags: android, android-camera, imagebutton

Here this a sample code that i have, here i have made a small app where the image can be captured or taken from the gallery and then subsequently filled as the imagebuttons background. So what i want is saving that image to the database and then retrieving it in a imageview :)

```
package com.example.imageviewok;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageButton a;
    ImageView b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 a = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                selectImage();

            }

        });
    }
    private File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
      String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
      OutputStream outStream = null;
     // String temp = null;
        File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "temp.png");
      if (file.exists()) {
       file.delete();
       file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "temp.png");

      }

      try {
       outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
       outStream.flush();
       outStream.close();

      } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return null;
      }
      return file;
     }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
     private void selectImage() {



            final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };



            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");

            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))

                    {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                        File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                        //pic = f;

                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


                    }

                    else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))

                    {

                        Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);



                    }

                    else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }

                }

            });

            builder.show();

        }



        @Override

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                if (requestCode == 1) {
                    //h=0;
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

                    for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {

                        if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {

                            f = temp;
                            File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                           //pic = photo;
                            break;

                        }

                    }

                    try {

                        Bitmap bitmap;

                        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();



                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),

                                bitmapOptions); 



                        a.setImageBitmap(bitmap);




                        String path = android.os.Environment

                                .getExternalStorageDirectory()

                                + File.separator

                                + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                        //p = path;

                        f.delete();

                        OutputStream outFile = null;

                        File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                        try {

                            outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);

                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
    //pic=file;
                            outFile.flush();

                            outFile.close();


                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                } else if (requestCode == 2) {



                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                   // h=1;
    //imgui = selectedImage;
                    String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);

                    c.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);

                    String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);

                    c.close();

                    Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));


                    Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");


                    a.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

                }

            }

        }   

}
```

Comment: What this code does is when an image button is clicked, it askes whether to capture an image or upload it from the gallery and then the captured or selected image will be the background image of the image button, but now all i want to do is save the imagebuttons background to the sqllite and then the code to retrieve and view it in a image view later on .

Comment: for saving image to squlite use Blob...

Comment: Question appears too broad, since an answer seems to require a how-to on database implementation. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) on implementing a database.  As for saving the image, you can  save the bytes to the database in a blob, but most advise saving your file name in the database, and your image as a seperate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save to `SQLite` use `BLOB` type when you are creating a field of the table and then save it with:

```
public byte[] getPhotoAsByte(){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if(getPhoto() != null){
        getPhoto().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then to get it back use:

```
Bitmap picture = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("Photo");
```